# Converting Complex Component Interface to Standard Web Service [Java]

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, soa

I have component that has complex interface with operations accepting non-primitive data or simple POJO.

What is the best practice (ways/methodologies) to convert this component interface to be standard Web Service interface that can be consumed by java and non-java clients, so that the service consumer can generate classes without problem using WSDL.

Can be used as it's? if not, is there a way to minimal change it without affecting operations' behavior?

The component interface has operations like:

```java
/** This is asynchronous method that needs to callback the ResultHandler
    interface which has to be implemented by the component user to handle
    operationOne result **/
public void operationOne(int id, ResultHandler handler);

/** I think there is no problem with the following operation for Web Services,
    when using data contracts. Correct me if I’m wrong! **/
public String operationTwo(int id, MyObject obj);
```

The ResultHandler interface:

```java
/** Note that this handler interface contains InputStream
    and Exception as parameters for the handling methods **/ 
interface ResultHandler {
    void onComplete(InputStream is); 
    void onFailure(IOException ioEx); 
}
```

Comment: Do you have tests in place for this?

Comment: I did not write the web serivce interface for this component yet becuase I do not know how to do it correctly and to be consumed by non-java clients without problems. However, in practice, is it possible to do what is explained in the question detailes?!

Comment: Are tests in place for the component already as it is now?  This is important because if you have all that scaffolding in place needed to do unit tests, it is usually not hard to adapt that into a webservice.

Comment: No, Tests not in place for this component. Yet, if we create unit tests, could you explain if possible, how to adapt that into a webservice?

Comment: Also, what will provide the web service stack. An application server? A standalone application using Endpoint.publish?

Comment: A standalone application

Answer (score 0):

You can use your objects in the webmethods, as they are converted to complex WSDL types, but keep in mind that this can only be done to a degree. You should have simple POJO's to transmit the data structures so that you get the benefit of the WSDL/code generation not the complex types you will be using to perform your business duties. Also a peace of advice, should REST/JSON over SOAP Web Services.

**UPDATE:**

The only way to effectively test your web services is by creating a moke for every call you have on your web service.

[Moq - How to mock web service call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204291/moq-how-to-mock-web-service-call)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a method that can invoke the component with the provided arguments and return a complete response.  For best results that method should not have side-effects.

Then add @WebService and @WebMethod annotations to it, and use Endpoint.publish(...) to create a small stand alone application publishing that web service.  The JAX-WS stack in Java 6 can autogenerate the WSDL from this.

See http://java.dzone.com/articles/jax-ws-hello-world for a full tutorial for doing this.

Comment: This means, I can not provide the same interface as the web service interface. I have to make another interface that has simple method in which its implementation invokes the component. Is this correct?

Comment: JAX-WS do support asynchroneous responses I believe, but I've never tried it.